# Qt dynamically add tasks to a threadpool queue with pause/stop functionality

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtconcurrent

**Context**

I have a long running process returning a result. This result *may* need further processing. There can also be multiple results ready simultaneously. Each one of these results that needs further processing may take a while too.

I need to take each one of those results, throw each into a queue of sorts and process each one, with the ability to start/stop this process.

**Problem:**

At the moment, I am limited to using a [QFuture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html) with a [QFutureWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html) and using either a [QtConcurrent::mapped()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#mapped) or [QtConcurrent::run()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run) function (the latter which doesn't support direct pause/stop functionality, [see note below](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run)).

The problem with the approech(es) mentioned above is it requires all results to be known up front, however to decrease the overall processing time, I would like to process each result as it comes in.

How can I effectively process create a thread pool with a queue of tasks?

Comment: To show the result and proceed with more sub-results from that one?

Comment: May be [QFuture::isResultReadyAt(int index)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#isResultReadyAt) can help? See also https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture - AsyncFuture is designed to enhance the function to offer a better way to use it for asynchronous programming. It provides a Promise object like interface.